# Better solution of elements in html and css

Tags: html, css, margin

I have some issues of elements position in html in css i have two examples, but can some one tell me what is right solution??

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left-col"></div>
<div class="right-col"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 1
CSS**

```
.wrapper{
width:100%;
}
.left-col{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.right-col{
width:50%;
float:right;
}
```

**Solution 2
CSS**

```
.wrapper{
width:100%;
}
.left-col{
width:50%;
float:left;
margin-right:-50%;
}
.right-col{
width:50%;
float:right;
margin-left:-50%;
}
```

There some - margins that someone use, is minus margin right solution?

Comment: `.wrapper{clear:both}` is a wrong way of clearing (see http://jsfiddle.net/vcq2N/). You must clear the element after the floated elements (not the container), or add `overflow: hidden` (or different than `visible`) to the container.

Comment: Forget the clear, i have just put simple example, i didnt asked about clear, I asked about - margin

Comment: as much as I experienced, when your page is `ltr`, margin-right have problem, except that you explain all margins means right, left, top and bottom... So, just use `margin-left` for two elements...

Comment: Why even use - margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solution 1 is better and more simple. As Oriol's example. The `div` after the wrapper overlaps the *wrapper*. You can use `table` also.

Answer (score 0):

CSS negative margins goes all the way back to CSS 1.0 and is even supported (if albeit poorly) but IE 4.0. I use negative margins for a few things, most notably perfect-pixel form fields. My site has a sign-in form where regardless of the width of the page/screen (e.g. 800x600 or 1920x1200) there will always be one pixel between all the form fields and it remains that way while you actively resize the window. It's also aided by using `padding` though keep in mind that you want to use padding sparingly, using `margin` is almost always the way to go. If you *think* you need padding on an element simply give the child element/children elements `margin` and you'll have a lot less layout issues. In general you want to avoid using `position` as it is not appropriate to use in most instances.

I recommend checking out my **[CSS `float` and `margin` tutorial](http://www.jabcreations.com/web/css/nested-divisible-elements)** to start with the basics and then use **[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)** with Firefox to use the DOM inspector to make LIVE changes to the DOM on my site for example so you can see how changing various CSS properties changes things.

Comment: @Oriol If you actually read what I wrote I specifically said "you want to use padding sparingly".